# Facebook does not return email for user?

Tags: php, facebook

This is the code I'm using to get information from Facebook:

```
$fbUsrId  = $facebook->getUser();
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope' => 'email'
        )
);

if ($fbUsrId) {
    $fbUsr = $facebook->api('/me');
    var_dump($fbUsr);
}
```

If I test in live it works fine, but from localhost Facebook returns only the user's name and email:

```
array (size=2)
  'name' => string 'xxx xxx' (length=18)
  'id' => string 'xxx' (length=15)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be two things here:

1. The user needs to have granted your app the `email` permission.
2. If you are using [v2.4 of the Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#v23tov24) then you should use the `?fields=field1,field2` syntax to declare all the fields you want the API to return. Which means you have to specify the fields explicitly like `/v2.4/me?fields=name,email` etc.